# ViewPager not working properly, when scrolling showing wrong positions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

TabLayout not working properly, when scrolling right it works correctly sometime but after scrolling left it shows same data. I'm calling Same Fragment class nine times in SectionPagerAdapter and trying to change data dynamically in Recyclerview.

### ViewPagerFragment Class

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
```

// private ArrayList tabName;

```
private String[] tabName = {"bangladesh","international","economy" ,"opinion","sports","entertainment", "features","life-style","northamerica"};

public ViewPagerFragment() {
}

public  ViewPagerFragment newInstance(String navigation) {
    ViewPagerFragment fragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(Constants.FRAG_A, navigation);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
    for(int i=0; i<=8; i++){
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(tabName[i]));
        }

    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount(),tabName);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));



    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); Log.v("pagerF ^&%&^^&:  ",tabName[tab.getPosition()]);
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });




    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Note that we are passing childFragmentManager, not FragmentManager
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount(),tabName);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mSectionsPagerAdapter!=null){
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

### SectionsPagerAdapter Class

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

int mNumOfTabs;
String[] tabName;


public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs, String[] tabName) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    this.tabName=tabName;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    HomeFragment comn = new HomeFragment();

      return comn.newInstance(tabName[position-1]);

}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.v("Count*^&*^  ", String.valueOf(mNumOfTabs));
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

}

### HomeFragment Class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public static String fragmentName = "";
HorizontalAdapter adapterhor; VerticalAdapter adapterver;
 ProthomAlo prothomAlo;
RecyclerView recyclerViewh, recyclerViewv;


public HomeFragment newInstance(String navigation) {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(Constants.FRAG_A, navigation);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    fragmentName = navigation;
    Log.v("home^^* :", navigation);
    return fragment;
}


public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);


    recyclerViewh =  view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_View_ho);
    recyclerViewv =  view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_View_ver);


    prothomAlo = new ProthomAlo();
    prothomAlo.getProthomAloPage(fragmentName, new ProthomAlo.ApiCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<SingleVertical> result) {
            adapterhor = new HorizontalAdapter(getActivity(), result);
            adapterver = new VerticalAdapter(getActivity(), result);

            recyclerViewh.setAdapter(adapterhor); recyclerViewv.setAdapter(adapterver);
            recyclerViewv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerViewh.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            // Log.v("$^&^$$^&", fragmentName);
        }
    });


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();



}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //adapterver.notifyDataSetChanged(); adapterhor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.v("home^^* :", fragmentName);


}
```

}

Comment: Not the answer but maybe part of it. Remember the positions are 0 based, judging by the way you are passing position-1 to the name array you are treating it as 1 based.

Comment: Is there any reason why do you want to return comn.newInstance(tabName[position-1]);   Cant you use return comn.newInstance(tabName[position]); without -1

Comment: I know I'm passing -1 value but I put a condition to overcome this issue. I'm doing this because in Log I see the position value is always plus one. But the problem is after scrolling the right side when getting back to left side the getItem() method not calling. So getting same data again. Any solution! Thanks for helping.